# How to connect to a local parse-server with Unity3d?

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, parse-server

I need to migrate from Parse.com to my own Parse-server. How could I initialize the Parse SDK on my Unity Project passing my server URL? The only editable variables on Unity Editor are `ApplicationId` and `DotNetKey`. I saw a .Net example where I could pass the `serverUrl` on application initialization (see below), but on Unity I could not find this option:

```
ParseClient.initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration {
    ApplicationId = "YOUR_APP_ID",
    ClientKey = "YOUR_APP_CLIENT_KEY",
    Server = "http://localhost:1337/parse"
});
```

I found that the `Parse.ParseClient` class has a internal `HostName` variable. How can I access that by reflection? I tried:

```
typeOf(ParseClient)
```

But this returns

> unknown type: Parse.ParseClient

Comment: they are shutting down so why create something relying on it

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? @Elltz, isn't this the correct way of redirecting to another server? What I have found on the internet, its the correct way. If not, can you please specify how to migrate it properly? Thank you.

Comment: I found a way using reflection, I can post the code when I get home, but what I done was: extend parseInitializer class and use reflection to change the ServerURL parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will wait for your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

************** SOLUTION *****************

```
public class ParseInitializer : ParseInitializeBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] public string hostURL; 

    public override void Awake() {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ParseInitializeBehaviour));
        var type = assembly.GetType("Parse.ParseClient");
        var prop = type.GetProperty("HostName", BindingFlags.Static 
                            | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        Uri uri = new Uri(hostURL;);
        prop.SetValue(type, uri, null);

        var s = (Uri)prop.GetValue(type, null);
        base.Awake();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you referenced has a typo. Its ParseClient.Initialize with an upper-case I. If you have the proper #using Parse; in your code, it should not flag an error.